# WordPress ignoring LIMIT / posts_per_page despite being in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, loop

Using WP query:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => $instance['count'],
    'meta_key' => 'mywp_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );
```

Let's get the request:

```
echo $myquery->request;
```

It returns:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
    ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
    WHERE
        1=1
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
        AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private )
        AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'mywp_post_views_count' )
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
    LIMIT 0, 5
```

This runs correctly in MySQL, giving me 5 post ID's. But WordPress returns 120 results!

```
echo '$myquery = ' . count( $myquery->posts );
```

returns: $myquery = 120

And I've checked when looping through:

```
 while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();
```

It does output the 120 unique posts, rather than the expected 5 posts.

I can confirm:

```
echo 'Count: '.$instance['count'];
```

Returns: Count: 5

I am running the latest stable WordPress (4.1), with no plugins apart from ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) - just my custom theme. Disabling this plugin has no effect, and default WordPress theme (2015) has the same issue.

I'm struggling to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What happens if you hard code the amount of posts per page. Do you gt the same output. At this stage I've got a felling this is not an issue with posts per page, but something else, either a custom filter or a typo somewhere in a name causing to return all posts

Comment: I've tried hard coding 5, instead of the $instance['count'] for posts per page - but unfortunately the same issue.

Comment: Add `'suppress_filters'=>true` to your arguments and report back

Comment: Unfortunately this has no affect either :(

Comment: Post your **complete** template. Something else on that page might be causing this. Did you make sure that your values are correct. Have you tried removing the meta_key and orderby parameters. Are you gettting the same result

Comment: the question do not make much sense. If the limit in the SQL used is 5, it is a DB bug if it returns 120 rows. There is some aditionl factor here which is not in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `'nopaging' => false` to your query construct.

I just had the same issue and it fixed it for me.

Comment: Downvote? This isn't reddit. Explain.